# issue with creating boost date from string

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I have a piece of code that tries to create a boost::gregorian::date object from a string format but I end up getting boost:gregorian::not_a_date_time even though the string seems to be fine. 
My code looks like this:

```
boost::gregorian::date getDateFromString(std::string date_str, std::string format) const
    {
        const std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale::classic(), new boost::gregorian::date_facet(format.c_str())); 
        std::istringstream is(date_str) ; 
        is.imbue(loc);
        boost::gregorian::date d; 
        is >> d; 
        return d; 
    }
```

To test this I call

```
boost::gregorian::date d = getDateFromString("20161101","%Y%m%d") ;
```

I get a not_a_date_time returned;
Instead if I do the following:

```
boost::gregorian::date d2 = boost::gregorian::date_from_iso_string( "20161101");
```

I receive a proper date object back. 
I need a generic function that can take variety of date formats. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `date_facet` instead of `date_input_facet`:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp>

boost::gregorian::date getDateFromString(std::string date_str, std::string format)
{
    const std::locale loc = std::locale(std::locale(), new boost::gregorian::date_input_facet(format.c_str())); 
    std::istringstream is(date_str); 
    is.imbue(loc);
    boost::gregorian::date d; 
    is.exceptions(~std::ios::iostate::_S_goodbit);
    is >> d; 
    return d; 
}

int main() {
    boost::gregorian::date d = getDateFromString("20161101","%Y%m%d"); 
    std::cout << d;
}
```

Note the use of `exceptions()` to see what the parser thinks is wrong if it fails to parse. You probably don't want to enable that unless you also handle the exception.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02cf4c6139636e33)</kbd>**

Prints

```
2016-Nov-01
```